# Enum 'entries' in Kotlin 1.9 cannot be resolved

Tags: kotlin

I updated Kotlin to the latest 1.9, where the Enum 'entries' should be stable.
However, when I try to use it it says `Unresolved reference: entries`

in my gradle.kts :

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
}
```

Is there something I should add to the gradle?

Comment: Do you see the error only in your IDE, or also in the command line when your run `gradle build`?

Comment: in the IDE it's underlined with red line (with Unresolved reference: entries).
And I cannot access anything inside entries. 

The project does compile if I just write "MyEnum.entries", but it doesn't really show anything

Comment: *The project does compile* - where? You mean you have no red in the IDE? Does the project compile fine when running `gradle build` from the command line? Because in general if that's the case, it's likely a bug in the IDE or an IDE misconfiguration. For instance, if your IDE doesn't have the version 1.9.0 of the Kotlin plugin, there is a chance it cannot understand enum `entries`

Comment: I do have red in the IDE, but it still runs if I just type "MyEnum.entries". 
Regrading the gradle, I ran the task of gradle build manually from the IDE's gradle tab. it seems to be working fine.
Regarding Project Settings - It says "Kotlin compiler version: 1.9.0" and "Language Version": Latest stable (1.8), the "API Version": Latest stable (1.8).
and in the gradle file I have a plugin "jvm" version "1.9.0"